# sql one segment has many methods but all of them should have one date how to check for the ones that dont have

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table looks like this:

```
method   year    segment     
ABC      2014    AB
CAB      2014    AB
PAU      2013    AB
COR      2015    CD
PRK      2016    IK
```

All segments should have same year. So I need to identify how many of them has different year. Its a mistake.

Result should be

```
method   year    segment 
PAU      2013    AB
```

or

> Error =  1

Can you help me with the code?
So far I tried something like this but it gives me whole list:

```
create table E1 as 
    select segment, dat_start
    from pd_segment a
    where a.segment in (select b.segment from pd_segment b
                        group by b.segment
                        having count (b.dat_start NE a.dat_start-1))
```

Comment: this one doesn't make any sense at all . what you want exactly ?

Comment: this one method has different date than the other method in the same segment. And its an error. Need to identify error.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database (and sas) tags.  Please tag the question with the database you are actually using.

Comment: thank you, sorry using this web-site for the first time and was in a hurry. But the problem is solved. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say our table name is "MyTable"

this query will report segment with more then 1 year:

```
select distinct segment from MyTable
Group by segment
having count(distinct year)>1
```

then if you want all the other columns data you can join this result with the table itself

```
select Mytable.* from MyTable join (
select distinct segment from MyTable
Group by segment
having count(distinct year)>1
) as x on x.segment=Mytable.segment
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using SAS and want this:

```
create table E1 as 
        select segment, dat_start
        from pd_segment a
        where a.segment in (select b.segment
                            from pd_segment b
                            group by b.segment
                            having min(b.dat_start) <> max(b.dat_start)
                           );
```

In SQL (and proc SQL), "not equal" is usually spelled `<>`.

Comment: Yes, Im using SAS. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM    (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [YEAR] 
        ORDER BY SEGMENT DESC) ROW_NO FROM @TABLE1
    ) T WHERE row_no <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have many segments and all you need are the methods where the year for the segments are not correct a simple query like below would do the trick:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM pd_segment
WHERE
   (dat_start NOT LIKE 2014 AND segment LIKE 'AB')
   OR (dat_start NOT LIKE 2015 AND segment LIKE 'CD')
   OR (dat_start NOT LIKE 2016 AND segment LIKE 'IK')
```

EDIT: Adding Result

```
method  dat_start   segment
PAU     2013        AB
```